# Netty, update sample code HttpStaticFileServerHandler to also return directory listing when a directory URL is specified

Tags: java, netty

I'm wondering how I could modified this great example handler found here:

https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/file/HttpStaticFileServerHandler.java

To also provide the ability to return a directory listing of files? Currently it will only serve files if the exact path and name to the file is specified, I would like to modify it such that I could specify a base path and get a listing of the files on the path

Thanks for any thoughts or ideas

Comment: The link is now dead, since master no longer exists, but as I answered below the question doesn't make sense if the link is updated anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try inserting the following at line #126.

```
if (file.isDirectory()) {
    String[] contents = file.list();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String name: contents) {
        sb.Append(name);
        sb.Append("\n");
    }

    HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, OK);
    response.setContent(ChannelBuffers.copiedBuffer(sb.toString(), CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
    response.setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");

    if (isKeepAlive(request)) {
        response.setHeader(CONTENT_LENGTH, response.getContent().readableBytes());
        response.setHeader(CONNECTION, HttpHeaders.Values.KEEP_ALIVE);
    }

    ChannelFuture future = e.getChannel().write(response);
    if (!(isKeepAlive(request)) {
        future.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
    }

    return;
}
```

Caution: I've just typed this up off the top of my head. You may get a compile error or two.

Comment: This works perfect, thanks Veebs! I just made a few tweaks to what you had so it would return the files wrapped with HTML links.

Answer (score 0):

i would imagine you would change the branch which returns an error if the target is not a "file" to instead return the directory listing as some sort of text/html file.